# CSS for custom Google search box

Tags: css, search

On the site I'm trying to build (https://www.dynomotion.com/test/index-search.htm) I have 2 problems:

1. the bottom border does not show up
2. the cursor is not exactly placed within the search box

Does anybody know I have done wrong?  I know it must have to do with the searchNav table which somehow conflicts with the .gsc-search-box style, but I don't know how exactly.

For the styling of the search, I use the following css:

```
#searchNav table { 
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#cse-search-form {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0;  
    margin:0;
}
  
.gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box,.gsc-search-box-tools
.gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box-focus {
    height: 25px;  
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#searchNav table` element has `margin: 1em` that overlaps your search box and prevents it from being selected.

Comment: That's it - thank you so much.  Now one last thing: is there a way to remove the cut-off "Enhanced by Google" in the search box?  Or how can I make it fit at least?

Comment: Actually, I just removed Google branding in the Search Engine settings, so the text is gone.  However, the box is still misaligned, and the curser half outside of the search box.  But margin is set to 0...

Comment: After some tweaking, it looks mostly fine now.  But there is one thing bothering me a lot, and I cannot figure out why this is happening: there is no bottom-border in the search box? Why?

Comment: Please vote up and accept the answer if it solved your problem:)

Comment: and regarding the border, your `tbody` is hiding it.

Comment: what do you mean by "tbody"?